# WebSetup Installer for configuring IIS settings

Tags: visual-studio, iis, configuration, installation

I have created a websetup using Visual Studio for deployment of a web application.

How can i get it to setup additional IIS settings ?

Like setting up wildcard, virtual directory, permissions, etc.

Basically stuff you can control using the inetmgr.

I would like to automate the configuration as much as possible.

Users always make mistake!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with WIX 3.5 installer.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229165/iis-web-deploy-create-virtual-directories/4229466#4229466). You can create a custom build task that can automate many of the IIS configuration steps you mentioned.

Comment: This is a great start but how can i edit the wild card settings?
Any links that document all IIS properties?

Comment: IIS 6: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3dff630e-1b6a-467e-af53-ae22946e0f40.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: So this only works for IIS 6? What happen if i run it on IIS 7 or the older IIS 5 ?

Comment: I need one API that's compatiable with all IIS version or else the webinstall is pointless!!

Comment: Well, the IIS6 metabase properties were replaced by xml configuration settings. Here is a list of the IIS6 to IIS7 mappings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347565.aspx?ppud=4

Comment: Well, then i will need to detect if they have IIS6 or IIS 7 and run different CustomBuildTask? I also notice there's a IIS6 compatiability installer one can just install. Need to check this out.