# Web Deploy create Virtual directory and add application

Tags: iis, msdeploy, webdeploy

I need to deploy web applications to an IIS 7.5. I have tried to create a [web deploy](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) package but I run into a problem.

Most of the applications I need to deploy are nested under virtual directories. Example:

```
Web Site/vDir/vDir/application
```

This seems to work if the virtual directories are already created. But if they are missing the application are instead created directly under the Website.

I create the package with the parameters `/t:build;Package`

Atm. I am using the cmd file to deploy with parameters `/Y /m:[Servername]`
I can't find a way to change the dest parameter. Do I need to use msdeploy directly instead?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229165/iis-web-deploy-create-virtual-directories) containing a good answer by [AaronS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26932/aarons).

He basically suggests creating a custom build task, including an example code.